# How to get a word from string in php?

Tags: php

This is my code

```
$datas= array("AAA","BBB","CCC","AAAAAA","BBBBBB","CCCCCCCCC");

$code = "AAAAAA-BBBBBB-CCCCCCCCC";

    for($i=0;$i<count($datas); $i++){           
             $pos = strpos($code ,$datas[$i]);          
             if($pos!== false){                 
                $this->valid_array[$i] = array("DATA"=> $datas[$i],"SPLITTER"=>substr($code ,strlen($datas[$i]),1));
             }
}
```

What I need is,

I need to find string inside $code from $datas array. I am using strpos function to find.

The problem is,

The strpos is returning 0 for first index of $datas. $datas[0] contain only 3 A.

But I need only the matched values. How can I check this as strict ?

Expected output is,
eg: `$code = "AAAAAA-BBBBBB-CCCCCCCCC";`
I am looping through the $datas array for checking the $datas elements included in the $code. if it is included I am constructing new "`$valid_array`" array. 
so if the code matches elements in the $datas array. the code is correct and I need to return the code.
Thanks.

Comment: If you use regular expressions, you can use a *word boundary* match.

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @Satish Sharma The $this->valid_array should have the same code if it is match

Comment: Do you want the whole of the string in `$code` to match one element of the array? At the moment it doesn't match any of them.

Comment: @Tom Fenech I want to match all the $code with any of the $datas array element, I mean $datas array must have code if I append last result

Comment: OK, so in your example you expect to find no matches?